# Background-image repeating when resize window (background-repeat is no-repeat)

Tags: html, css

My background image is repeat even though in css I have `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Why is this happening?

This happens when I resize my window.

I have a TV on background as video layer.

HTML:

```
<div class="tv">
   <video width="98%" height="78%" controls="controls">
          <source src="img/showreel.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tv{
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: url(img/tv.png) center center;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  width: 100%;
}

.showreel-video{
  position:relative;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `background-repeat: no-repeat;` instruction is currently being overridden by the `background:...;` attribute because the latter also accepts a repeat/no-repeat instruction and is placed *after*.

So, you must either add no-repeat to your background attribute like this:

```
background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/) center center no-repeat;
```

or move `background-repeat: no-repeat;` after the background instruction.

Comment: This answer actually explains whats the issue, it gets overridden with the shorthand property in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `background-repeat` and set background something like the following:

```
 background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/) center center no-repeat;
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/cacofotaqo/1/

Comment: I think it is because using the parent property with child property.

Comment: There is nothing like parent and child property, one is a shorthand, other is a general declaration

Comment: @Mr.Alien I just forgot the nomenclature of both ways! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your css the background-repeat is being overwritten by the defaults for your background declaration as CSS processes rules from top to bottom. If you switch background-repeat and background then it will work:

```
background: url(img/tv.png) center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
```

Comment: Or Separating each property.