# Background-img is resizing and repeating

Tags: html, css, web, size, background-image

I'm doing a website and i added a background-img behind my contact form. Firstly, some screen of my page:

Here's my page in fullscreen:

[image]

Here's my page when i resize it:

[image]

As you can see, the background-img of my div is repeated when i resize my page. I want it to keep the same size even if the image will be cutted. I tried to change the width but my div's width is changing too and that's not the behavior I want. I also tried to change the background with the fixed attribute but it seems not working.

I hope you will be able to help me !

Thanks

Comment: Please read: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Possible repetition of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27106982/background-image-repeating-when-resize-window-background-repeat-is-no-repeat)
If not please notify

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I looked at w3s and it worked for me. I used background-size attribute

Answer (score 1):

use these css properties

```
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```